# Smooth Manifolds with finite dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M_1,M_2$ and $N$ be manifolds of dimension $m_1,m_2$ and $n$ respectively. Prove that the map $(f1, f2): N → M_1 × M_2$ is $C^∞$ off $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $C^∞$.

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since the charts of $M_1\times M_2$ are just of the form $(\varphi\times\psi)(a,b)=\varphi(a)\times\psi(b)$, you can easily reduce this to the Euclidean case.

Then, use the fact that a map $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth if and only if its coordinate funcdtions $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ are smooth (this is basic advanced calculus).